# Snippets: Redirecting on the page stops the script execution. Why?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

If you execute the following script, the console.logs never execute. Why? I don't see a reason why it should stop running on page switch.

My use case was actually too simple to justify puppeteer, but seems like for such things you still need it.

```
const timer = (delay) =>
        new Promise((resolve) => {
          setTimeout(resolve, delay);
        });

window.location.href='https://www.google.com/';

// ###### NEVER GETS HERE!! #######

console.log('wait....')
await timer(5000);
console.log('done')
document.querySelector('div.modal__body button.button.button--responsive.button--primary').click();
```

Comment: A script is a part of the page's JS environment. The page (and its environment) is destroyed upon navigation.

Comment: @wOxxOm I know that this is the case for inline scripts, I just don't know why they implemented it like that, when they could go another route. Snippets could be more than that.

Comment: Any code that runs inside the context of a page is terminated when the page is navigated, there's no away around it.